# ASP.NET FileUpload control not working inside Wizard control

Tags: asp.net, .net-2.0

I have a Wizard control with one of the pages containing a FileUpload control. I want to access the file stream at the point of the final page of the wizard but this doesn't seem to work.

As far as I can see, you can only access the file stream for the posted file on the postback which occurs immediately after the control has been used.  As the file will ultimately be put into a DB record I could save it at this point, but I'd rather avoid this if possible.

Does anyone know of a workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not used this control myself but as it's based around the HTML standard INPUT control I think you are stuck with having to receive the file on the post-back that processes that control.

The difficulty in circumventing this would be around how to pull the file from the client system when you are effectively sandboxed from the local filesystem, hence the need for the upload control.

I would suggest that you store the file into your DB blob (or as a temp file on the filesystem, probably need a unique filename; I find a GUID works nicely) and then use the Session object to retain that reference to the end of the process. The only other alternative I can think of that doesn't involve major work would be to move the file upload to the last page of your wizard.

Answer (score 2):

You could have the displaying of your individual wizard stages managed client-side using CSS/jQuery rather than keep POSTing back to the server? That way, your only POST (resulting in the upload) will be at the end of the Wizard.

Comment: Good lateral thinking, nice answer.